# Why would a trigger fire on insert and update for the same transaction?

Tags: apex, trigger, triggercontext

I'm building a trigger, and when I create a new record it fires on both `Trigger.isInsert` and `Trigger.isUpdate` context.

```
trigger Custom_Trg on Custom__c (before insert, before update) {
    if(Trigger.isInsert) {
        System.debug('inserted');
    }else if(Trigger.isUpdate) {
        System.debug('updated');
    }
}
```

Why could this be happening?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe there's other triggers on that object that cause an update after a record is inserted?

Or maybe there's workflow on the object that causes a field update? That will in turn trigger the update trigger.

Comment: Yeah, it looks like there is a workflow involved causing the update. How could I write the trigger so it doesn't execute after workflow?

Comment: You probably mean to ask: how can I make sure the trigger only runs once for each insert/update (otherwise you wouldn't have it triggered before update anyway). You can do that by using a static variable. It's described here: http://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000133752&language=en_US

Answer (score 0):

The trigger you've written is both a BEFORE INSERT and BEFORE UPDATE trigger.

```
trigger Custom_Trg on Custom__c (before insert, before update) {
```

In essence, by definition, you've created to fire both when a record is Inserted or is Updated. Anytime a record is *going* to be inserted or updated on that object, your trigger *will* fire before any After Insert or After Update triggers and/or workflow is executed.

That can happen when there's a VF page that's executed that's used to create or update a record, when batch jobs are run that either insert or update data, or when any kind of time based workflow occurs.

If you only want it to fire on one or the other, then you need to edit the trigger to something like this if say you want it to only run when a new record is being inserted:

```
trigger Custom_Trg on Custom__c (before insert) {
```

If you want it to fire After Insert, change it as follows:

```
trigger Custom_Trg on Custom__c (after insert) {
```

Once a trigger fires, it can fire again for a multitude of reasons. Workflow is probably the most common one. In your case, after an insert, there may very well be workflow that happens which results in the record having been updated. So before the update to the record is saved, the before update portion of your trigger would fire.

If there happened to be an after insert trigger on your Custom__c object, there might be workflow that would follow the after insert trigger's operations that would appear as an update to the object, causing the after update portion of your trigger to fire.

For more, see the [Apex Documentation on Triggers](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_triggers.htm).

Comment: This is good info but doesn't really address the question.  I think he is saying that when he inserts a record, the system is writing to the debug log inside both the insert and update logic.  While your answer explains some features of triggers, I believe the asker already knows this as he already has checks within the trigger checking the context.  I believe he is looking for more specific info as to why its making into both IF statements on an insert.

Comment: Ahh, gotcha! Yes, understand. Then workflow fires after the insert which then triggers the update to fire. I didn't explain that aspect clearly. Its not always easy to tell what someone is looking for from their description. Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: Agreed it is tough sometimes.  No worries, just wanted to point it out.

Answer (score 0):

Something that I faced recently at work:

1. Before Insert is fired (here let's say you update a field)
2. After Insert is fired
3. Before Update is fired (and the reason is that you made some update in the before insert)
4. After Update is fired

Answer (score -1):

I am a Salesforce newbie but in the SQL Server world (where I come from) I see this all of the time.  It happens because an insert IS an update to the object. Just sayin' ..

Comment: That's not applicable to the force.com platform unless there are other processes performing database operations;